# Issue with @Input, ngOnInit() and formGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am strugling with this in angular (5) :

I want to have a form initialized with somes values.

To do so, I created a component "group-detail".

For the html part of this component (group-detail.component.html), I have the following :

```
<div *ngIf="group">
  ...
  <!-- Stuff before the form like ({{group.questionGroupId}} -->
  ...
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup" class="group-detail-form">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Group Name" formControlName="groupName" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Creation Date" formControlName="creationDate">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="group.lastModificationDate">
      <input matInput placeholder="Last Modification " formControlName="lastModificationDate">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="group.isDeleted == true">
      <input matInput placeholder="Deleted" formControlName="isDeleted">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="group.deletedOn">
      <input matInput placeholder="Deleton on" formControlname="deletedOn">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Description" formControlname="description">
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
  ...
  <!-- Stuff after the form (buttons, ...) -->
  ...
</div>
```

So I have a formGroup ("formGroup") containing a few inputs with a formControlName.

In the component typescript, I have the following :

```
export class GroupDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() group: Group;

  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private qgroupService: QGroupService,
    private location: Location
  ) { 
      this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        groupName: new FormControl({ value: ''}, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
        creationDate: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
        lastModificationDate: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
        isDeleted: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
        deletedOn: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
        description: new FormControl({ value: '' })
      });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getGroup();
      this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        groupName: new FormControl({ value: this.group.groupName }, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
        creationDate: new FormControl({ value: this.group.creationDate, disabled: true }),
        lastModificationDate: new FormControl({ value: this.group.lastModificationDate, disabled: true }),
        isDeleted: new FormControl({ value: this.group.isDeleted, disabled: true }),
        deletedOn: new FormControl({ value: this.group.deletedOn, disabled: true }),
        description: new FormControl({ value: this.group.description })
      });
    }

    getGroup(): void {
      const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('questionGroupId');
      this.qgroupService.getGroup(id).subscribe(group => this.group = group);
    }

}
```

So, I have to make a new instance of formGroup in the constructor otherwise I get an error. After that, the ngOnInit() is supposed to fetch the group with a particular id and rebuild the form with values inside.
I know the qgroupService is returning the group, or at least, when I log from the method qgroupService.getGroup(), I have the group Object after the http get request.

I don't understand yet is why i get this error :

#### TypeError: Cannot read property 'groupName' of undefined

Because I thought that getGroup() would return the group to

#### @Input group : Group

And that I could use it to remake my form with initial values.

Maybe I'm complicating thing too much.

Any advice would be appreciated (I'm still discovering Angular 5 and Typescript),

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you instantiate the formGroup 2 times? To keep your code a little bit cleaner I would suggest you to refactor it to use the FormBuilder class

Comment: You are creating the instance of the group twice, that's why you are getting undefined. You don't need to initialise it in the constructor, just declare `formGroup: FormGroup` and then initialise it in ngOnInit

Comment: Yes, I don't need both instantiation for sure. The problem was, I think, the fact that I don't get access to `this.group` after getGroup()... So `this.group` was only defined in the subscribe function and by the time the subscribe completes, I suppose the formGroup was already executed. But I'll need to read more about this. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some trouble with implementing something very similar to this. If I've understood correctly, here are some suggestions that may be helpful:

1) Only set `this.formgroup` once. Don't reset it.

2) In `getGroup()`, iterate over the `this.group`'s keys to set the relevant values for each of your `this.formGroup` `formControls`:

```
getGroup(): void {
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('questionGroupId');
  this.qgroupService.getGroup(id).subscribe(group => {
      this.group = group;
      for (const key in group) {
           this.formGroup.controls[key].setValue(group[key]);
      }
  });
}
```

3) If the group is being passed in as `@Input()`, is `getGroup()` necessary at all? If it's not necessary, the loop above could be called in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  for (const key in this.group) {
      this.formGroup.controls[key].setValue(this.group[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much, your solution is working out for me.
I'm still wondering why I could not use this.group (undefined) after getGroup() in ngOnInit(). I guess I'll have to read more about Angular and Typescript in general. Thank you again.

Comment: Happy to help. As for your remaining question, it could've been due to a race condition associated with `subscribe()`.